# My python post request doesn't work in my login bot

Tags: authentication, python-requests, http-headers, http-post, bots

I am trying to code a program that can automate the process of logging into an account on 'https://www.coolmod.com/'. The ´form´ is formed by 3 inputs: email, password and a value of '1' stored on a variable which name's a random number generated each time you acces to the login page. So first I must `GET` to the login page to identify this random number and then submit the payload via `POST` request. For each of the request methods I'm using a set of headers, extracted from my browser's (Chrome) inspector. `headers1` are the request headers that show when I get to 'https://www.coolmod.com/web/auth/login' and `headers2` the request headers that show up when I get redirected to 'https://www.coolmod.com/index.php' after having submited my credentials.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep


login_url = 'https://www.coolmod.com/web/auth/login'


headers1 = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6',
    'dnt': '1',
}

headers2 = {
    'Host': 'www.coolmod.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '106',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://www.coolmod.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://www.coolmod.com/web/auth/login',
    'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6',
    'dnt': '1',
}

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers1)

r1 = s.get(login_url)
print(f'1st request resp headers: {r1.headers}')
s.headers.update(headers2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'html.parser')
first_token = soup.findAll('input', attrs={'type': 'hidden', 'value': '1'})[1]['name']
payload = {
    'jform[email]': 'email',
    'jform[password]': 'password',
    'remember-me': 'on',
    first_token: '1'
}

sleep(1)


r2 = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
print(f'2nd request resp headers: {r2.headers}')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup2.title)
```

The 1st request works fine (GET), but the second one (POST) gets the wrong response headers when compared to the same task executed on chrome. I get a `200` after the `POST` and remain on the login site, which means that there must be something wrong with my payload or headers I gess. If someone could help my I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#2nd request resp headers: {...'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
#vs expected resp headers: {...'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Set-Cookie': 'SVI=3c59dc0...path=/', 'Set-Cookie': 'SGI=167...path=/',...}
```

Comment: Please detail the response you're getting from the website. Furthermore, getting "stuck" on the same page probably means there's an issue with the login. Try to debug the page by displaying the html response inside your browser.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. I have been making some changes to the code. To my understanding, cookies are automatically handled by the `session()` object so I've deleted all the extra cookies code. Also I've added some more headers just to be sure that I'm not being detected as a bot (all of the requested headers that chrome uses when I do this actions as a casual user), both the `get` request and the `post`. The 1st request works fine (GET), but the second one (POST) gets the wrong response headers when compared to the same task executed on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, I there where multiple forms and inputs in the page which resulted in me selecting the wrong TOKEN. Also most of the headers where not necessary.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: The problem was that there were multiple tokens in the page's content, and with the attributes that I used with bs4 to find the token needed as input inthe form were to generic and so, I was not selecting the specific token that I wanted, but another one instead.